# print_r - format SimpleXLSX data?

Tags: php, xlsx

Suppose I had a excel xlsx document called *names* with a couple of entries and wanted to print out the names from a php file.

```
include 'simplexlsx.class.php';

  $xlsx = new SimpleXLSX('names.xlsx');
  print_r( $xlsx->rows() );
```

This would print:

> Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => John [1] => Smith ) [1] => Array ( [0]
>   => Steven [1] => Brake ) [2] => Array ( [0] => Carter [1] => Firen ) [3] => Array ( [0] => Juan [1] => Lahyno ) [4] => Array ( [0] => Sarah
>   [1] => Parker ) [5] => Array ( [0] => Julie [1] => Roberts ) [6] =>
>   Array ( [0] => Will [1] => Smith ) [7] => Array ( [0] => Angelina [1]
>   => Jolie ) )

Is there a way to print out the data in a readable way? Or does print_r not allow formatting of an array passed to it?

Comment: print_r() ___is___ printing a formatted array, as a simple, human-readable display or keys and values; note that it uses simple carriage returns as well, which won't render in a browser unless you put it within html <xmp> or <pre> tags. But if you want other formatting applied, use foreach() loops to iterate over it and format the values however you wish, e.g. in a tabular structure

Comment: Define `readable way`

Answer (score 1):

If you add

```
echo '<pre>';
print_r( $xlsx->rows() );
```

Then you see somethiink like this:

```
Array ( 
    [0] => Array 
        (
            [0] => John [1] => Smith 
        ) 
    [1] => Array 
        (   
            [0] => Steven [1] => Brake 
        )
...
```

I hope this will help you